# How do I combine multiple datepicker parameters into one Gravity Forms script?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to customize the datepicker within Gravity Forms so that users cannot pick weekends and also add some blackout days throughout the year. I can get each individual parameter to work, but I have no idea how to combine them into one script, and running two scripts doesn't work either. Can you please help me out? I'm clueless with Javascript and am surprised I got this far.

Script 1: No Weekends

```
<script>
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 3 && fieldId == 7 ) {
        optionsObj.firstDay = 1;
        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends;
    }
    return optionsObj;
});
    
</script>
```

Script 2: Disable certain days

```
<script>
gform.addFilter( 'gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function( optionsObj, formId, fieldId ) {
    if ( formId == 3 && fieldId == 7 ) {
        var disabledDays = ['09/15/2021', '09/16/2021', '09/17/2021'];
        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = function(date) {
            var checkdate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date);
            return [disabledDays.indexOf(checkdate) == -1];
        };
    }
    return optionsObj;
});
    </script>
```

I pulled this info from here: https://docs.gravityforms.com/gform_datepicker_options_pre_init/#5-disable-specific-dates

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gform.addFilter('gform_datepicker_options_pre_init', function (optionsObj, formId, fieldId) {
    if ( formId == 3 && fieldId == 7 ) {
        optionsObj.firstDay = 1;
        optionsObj.beforeShowDay = function (date) {
            var disabledDays = ['09/15/2021', '09/16/2021', '09/17/2021'],
                currentDate = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', date),
                day = date.getDay();
 
            return [!(disabledDays.indexOf(currentDate) != -1 || day == 0 || day == 6 )];
        };
    }
 
    return optionsObj;
});
```